# Facebook connect with Phonegap iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, cordova

I'm building a Phonegap application for iOS and I'm trying to include the Facebook connect framework.

I followed all the steps twice from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin , but it keeps giving the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSBJSON", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FacebookConnectPlugin.o
"_SecRandomCopyBytes", referenced from:
  +[FBCrypto randomBytes:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
  -[FBCrypto encrypt:additionalDataToSign:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
"_kSecRandomDefault", referenced from:
  +[FBCrypto randomBytes:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
  -[FBCrypto encrypt:additionalDataToSign:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does somebody know what the problem is here?

With kind regards

Answer (score 4):

You have to add five other frameworks and libraries (AdSupport, Accounts, libsqlite3, Security and Social) to use the Facebook SDK.

see also: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Means that the compiler is trying to compile for i386, ie for Mac OS X. Not the architecture you want, if you're building an iOS app. You must have missed a compiler setting somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Add cordova.framework into your package...i think the problem will be solved